# How to change Title of each plot in sns.relplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

Using the following code below:

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.relplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", col="time")
```

I am getting this figure:
[image]

However, I'd like to change the title for each plot, something like "Plot A" for the left one and "Plot B" for the right one. I am using the following command to change the title;

```
g.set_titles('Plot A')
```

But that changes the title of both of them to **Plot A**. How to change it?

Comment: `g.axes[0,0].set_title('Plot A')` and `g.axes[0,1].set_title('Plot B')`

Comment: Great, thank you :)